# Using a register in a .vimrc mapping

Tags: vim, vim-registers

I'm doing a job involving multiple modifications of HTML template files in which values to be replaced are designated in the template with tokens such as "%%ARTICLE_DATE". I'd like to use the "+" or "*" (clipboard, X-clipboard) vim registers in a mapping in my .vimrc to set up a search using the value in the clipboard. For instance:

```
cmap <esc>q %s/%%ARTICLE_DATE/<something>/c
```

So if I had "June 12, 2016" in my X-clipboard from another app, I could key Esc-q and have

```
:%s/%%ARTICLE_DATE/June 12, 2016/c
```

in my vim command line, and I could press Enter and selectively replace the matched tokens. Is there a functional representation of clipboard contents which I could use for <something> which would do this?

Comment: `<c-r>*` or `<c-r>+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different ways you could do this.

1. The easy way:

   ```
   cmap <esc>q %s/%%ARTICLE_DATE/<C-r>*/c
   ```

   This doesn't use any fancy tricks. It just uses the `<C-r>` key to insert the contents of a register.
2. The robust way:

   ```
   cmap <expr> <esc>q "%s/\V%%ARTICLE_DATE/".escape(getreg("*"), "\\/")."/c"
   ```

   This uses an "expr" mapping, which means it will evaluate the vimscript to a string and run that string as a mapping. This has some extra things in place to make sure that if you have a slash (forward or backward) in your register, it won't screw up the search.

Comment: Why not just `%s/%%ARTICLE_DATE/\=getreg("*")/c`?

Comment: @melpomene That would work to. I just happen to really like `<expr>` mappings. And it doesn't escape too.

Comment: Why would I need to escape anything there?

Comment: @melpomene Because if your register has a slash or a backslash in it, it will break your `:%s` command.

Comment: No, it won't. Did you try it?

Comment: Both DJMcMayhem's "easy way" and melpomene's solution work OK. The "robust way" inserts ".escape(getreg("*"), "\ [sic] into the document and falls out of the search parse, doing no confirmation. It's probably a punctuation thing. I deal with a bunch of languages and have never had the bandwidth to study vim scripting. I just follow recipes.

Comment: @LindsayHaisley Did you forget the `<expr>` bit?

Comment: OK, being careful with the <expr> syntax, all of these work OK. @DJMcMayhem, when put this into a .vimrc, the "\V" needs a double escape, as in **"%s/\\V%%ARTICLE_DATE/ ....**. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

@DJMcMayhem answered your direct question. However, this does not feel Vim-like and using `cmap`'s are tricky as they expand in unexpected places (e.g. `/<esc>q`).

#### Make a command

Making a command which does this is pretty easy.

```
command! -range=% -nargs=+ TemplateReplace keeppaterns <line1>,<line2>s/<args>/\=@*/gc
```

Now you can do `:TemplateReplace %%ARTICLE_DATE` and it will replace with the `"*` register.

#### Making use of `:s` and mappings

Use a mapping which creates a substitution command from the current search pattern.

```
nnoremap gS :<c-u>%s//\=@*/gc<cr>
```

Set your search pattern (e.g. `/%%ARTICLE_DATE` then use `gS`.

Or take a register as an argument:

```
nnoremap gS :<c-u>%s//\=getreg(v:register)/gc<cr>
```

Use `"*gS` to replace the current search pattern with contents of a register, this case it would be `"*` register.

#### Visual Star mapping

Use a [visual star](https://vimawesome.com/?q=visual%20star) mapping like the following to simplify setting the search pattern.

```
xnoremap * :<c-u>let @/=@"<cr>gvy:let [@/,@"]=[@",@/]<cr>/\V<c-r>=substitute(escape(@/,'/\'),'\n','\\n','g')<cr><cr>``
```

Now you can visually select your text then use `*` to set the search pattern.

#### Use the `gn` motion

Set your search pattern (e.g. `/%%ARTICLE_DATE`) then do `cgn<c-r>*<esc>`. Now you can use `n` and `.` to make your replacements.

[Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Operating on search matches using gn](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/).

This approach would also benefit from a visual star mapping as well.

#### Substitution preview with traces.vim

[Traces.vim](https://github.com/markonm/traces.vim) will allow you to preview your substitution while you writing it. Sort of like `'incsearch'`, but for `:s`. This doesn't directly help you with your current problem, but might help give you feedback and catch errors in the future.

Comment: This is good information, but for this purpose, the KISS principle applies pretty strictly. I need to reformat some old website pages, packed with information, into a more modern HTML5 format with strong reliance on CSS. It's repetitive and labor intensive. I want to highlight information in a browser window and then run a controlled search and replace in vim with the highlighted information as the replacement string, without having to copy and paste. It's simple information - names and dates - and the simplest solution works just fine. I've already finished most of the job.

Comment: Quite simply, I'm transcribing a series of articles, already online on our website, to a format defined by a template with an index and a number of repetitive sections, each with tokens, %%ARTICLE_SOURCE, %%ARTICLE_DATE, %%ARTICLE_AUTHOR, etc. I have set up a series of cmap lines in my .vimrc using DJMcMayhem's "robust way" - <esc>as for author, <esc>ad for date, etc. The workflow is 1) highlight the text on the _old_ website, 2) switch to my vim window, 3) go to command mode and key the proper sequence, and 4) hit Enter and manage the substitutions from within vim. It's very fast.